# Find first element match between two sequences in linear time?

Tags: string, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Lets say we have two sequences x = {x_i : i elem [1,M]} and y = {y_i : i elem [1,N]} with an ordered alphabet. Is it possible to find the smallest (if any) pair (i, j) such that x_i = y_j?

The trivial O(n^2) time O(1) space algorithm just has you compare every element of either sequence together keeping track of the smallest difference in distance from the start of the sequence.

A O(n log n) time O(n) space algorithm just sorts the sequences and compares while keeping tracking of the smallest/largest element.

I can't think of a linear time algorithm though and I'm not sure what this problem would be called.

Comment: It can be done in O(max{m,n}log(min{m,n})) by sorting only the smaller list, and using binary search on it while iterating the bigger list. I am pretty sure it is too similar to element distinctness problem to overcome the nlogn boundary (unless hashing is allowed and cheap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note it can be done in `O(max{m,n}log(min{m,n}))` by sorting only the smaller list, and using binary search on it while iterating the bigger list.

In addition, you can use a hash table to index one list to pairs `x_i->min{j, x_j = x_i }` - this takes expected linear time and space.

Then, simply iterate the other list, and look for `y_i` in the table, while maintaining the minimal value found so far.

This totals in O(n) space and time on average case.

Pseudo code:

```
table = {}
for each element x_i in x in ascending order of i:
  if x_i is not in table:
    table[x_i] = i
best_pair = (-1,-1)
for each element y_j in y:
  if y_j in table:
    if (table[y_j],j) is "better" than best_pair:
      best_pair = (table[y_j], j)
return best_pair
```

I am pretty sure it is too similar to [element distinctness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem) to overcome the Omega(nlogn) boundary without using hashing, but no proof comes to mind.

Comment: That's the name I was looking for, thank you! Both your algorithm and templatetypedef's solves the problem but yours solves it more generally when you have an infinite alphabet size (e.g you have a sequence of strings!).

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to build a table of size |Σ|, where Σ is your alphabet, that associates each symbol with the first position it occupies in the string x. You can then iterate over x and, for each character, record the first position of that character in x in the table. You can then do a pass over the string y and, for each character of y, consult the table to find the first time that character appears in string x. You didn't mention in your question how you're defining the "smallest" pair (lexicographical order? minimize i + j? something else?), but you should be able to generate all possible pairs and then take the minimum of them in linear time.

Overall, this takes time O(n + |Σ|) and using space O(|Σ|), so if your alphabet isn't too large this is pretty fast. If your alphabet is large, just use a hash table and this ends up being expected O(n) time with O(n) space.

Comment: I left the ordering of the pair (i, j) ambiguous in the latest version but initially I was interested in any general metric. I like your answer since it takes care of the case of a small alphabet, it's quite similar to amit's more general answer that can take care of arbitrary alphabet sized sequences.

Answer (score 0):

O(n+m) algo:

- start with i = 0 and j = 0
- if x[i] < y[j] i++
- if x[i] > y[j] j++
- if x[i] == y[j] => you found it

Obviously you also need to check for arrays boundaries.

Comment: Arrays are not sorted.